# React-Native 'syscall' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0 - syscall(2) is unsupported

Tags: ios, react-native

I get the following error after i run my iOS react-native app with xcode.

```
'syscall' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0 - syscall(2) is unsupported; please switch to a supported interface. For SYS_kdebug_trace use kdebug_signpost().
```

I use iOS 12.0 and react-native 0.68.0
React is 17.0.2

i already tried this solution but with no effect.

https://github.com/google/glog/pull/685

Can someone help me with this problem?